# ghdl missing util.misc_conv_pkg ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, vhdl, ghdl

I am trying to compile vhdl code using ghdl compiler. However I am missing two util libraries:

> > *util.misc_conv_pkg*    and
> >     *util.vstring*.

therefore this code is not working

```
LIBRARY util;
  USE util.misc_conv_pkg.ALL;
  USE util.vstring.ALL;
```

I have tried all possible installations methods I found: 
http://ghdl.free.fr/site/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Installation
or
https://sourceforge.net/p/ghdl-updates/wiki/Installing%20ghdl/

But it is still not working. How do i fix this.

Comment: You need to find the source for those packages and compile them into the `util` library. They are part of the project you're working on, not part of VHDL.

Comment: and not part of a ghdl distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the source for those packages and compile them into the `util` library. They are part of the project you're working on, not part of VHDL.

If you can't find them, just comment out the `USE` clauses. Then one of two things will happen...

1. They aren't actually used at all, in which case the project will compile and work fine without them, and you have cleaned it up by eliminating unnecessary dependencies. It's amazing how often this is the case with those deprecated `std_logic_arith` packages.
2. Some functions or declarations from them are used, in which case compilation will fail with a fairly accurate description of what's missing. (Add the first few to the question if necessary).

Normally with a "util" library, the functionality is fairly obvious, so you can either find a more standard or more portable way of doing it, or you can write your own package that fulfils JUST the bits required for this project.

Comment: @akaAlso So did you find the sources, or did you have to work around their absence?

Comment: I have to find a way to work around it.. someone used it and it did work for him by just installing ghdl. However he is using windows and has a different installation. This means I also have to install windows

Comment: Installing Windows won't solve the problem. He must have those sources somewhere, that's all you need.

Comment: he said he doesn't.. I also read something like ghdl has not made some updates for linux for quite some times.<https://sourceforge.net/p/ghdl-updates/wiki/Debian%20Instructions/>. I want to give it a try since I don't have any other option.

Comment: That just means you can't get a new ghdl via apt-get. The packages on sourceforge are the latest release, or you can get the development branch via github.com/tgingold/ghdl . But as above, that's not the problem. I recommend you do as I suggested, and add what's actually missing when you compile without the `use` clauses to the question.